# Declare global temporary table, insert and delete statements in one DB2 Stored procedure

Tags: db2

I have a requirement where I will pass member number as an input and need to delete entries corresponding to that member number from all existing tables.

Can someone please guide me here. Also, please advise on how to use DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE, insert and delete in one stored procedure.

Thanks much.

Comment: please attach what did you try so far.

Comment: @KiranManiya - Here it is
CREATE PROCEDURE MEM_DELETE 
 (IN I_MEM_NR CHAR(8))

LANGUAGE SQL 


BEGIN
    DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.R1(M1_NR DECIMAL(11) NOT NULL)
    CCSID EBCDIC ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

 INSERT INTO SESSION.R1 SELECT M1_NR FROM M1TB0.CLAIM WHERE MEM_NR IN (I_MEM_NR);


    DELETE
    FROM M1TB0.BANK_DETAILS_BENEFICIARY
    WHERE M1_NR IN (SELECT M1_NR FROM SESSION.R1);

Comment: @alok Use EDIT to add code to your question, don't put code in comments because it's not searchable. When asking for help with Db2, always put into your question the exact Db2-platform (z/os,  i-series/as400, or Linux/Unix/Windows) or use the dedicated tags for that purpose.  If you show code, show the *error message* in full if there is one.   Use the Db2 Knowledge-Centre online to learn from the SAMPLES for your platform.